# Switch styles for special words

Tags: style, button

I want to create a Cloze test in *Mathematica*.

I want to have text in a text cell and leave some words blank (to be filled in by students).

With a button I want be able to switch between styles for those words (visible red or invisible and replaced by dots for example).
How could this be done?

Comment: Should those blanks be editable?

Comment: Not necessarily. Originally I was looking for some global setting like in TeX which I could change.

Answer (score 3):

One out of many possible ways:

```
hideF = Row[List @@ StringReplace[#,  w: Alternatives @@ #2 :> Style["...", Blue]]] &;
highlightF = Row[List @@ StringReplace[#, w: Alternatives @@ #2 :> Style[w, Red, Bold]]] &;

text = StringTake[ExampleData[{"Text", "LoremIpsum"}], 200];
words = {"amet", "rutrum", "feugiat"};

FlipView[{hideF[text, words], highlightF[text, words]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for all the possibilities. Originally I was looking for a global setting changing some "marked" words in text cells. But the answer from kglr might work well.

Answer (score 3):

Just as a start:

```
f = DynamicModule[{col = White}, 
    DynamicWrapper[Dynamic[Style[#, col]], 
     If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], col = Red, col = White]]] &;
DynamicModule[{dat = (f /@ {"pig", "dog"})}, 
 Dynamic[Grid[MapThread[{#1, #2} &, {{
      "Pork comes from a ", "An animal that barks is a"}, 
     UnderBar /@ dat
     }], Alignment -> Left]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
{Button["White highlight", FrontEndTokenExecute["FontColor", White]],
 Button["Red highlight", FrontEndTokenExecute["FontColor", Red]]}
```

then type:  "Here is some random text"

Double click on a word then click on a color highlight button.